# How to take last Observable sequence value after some time after sequence stopped produced elements in Reactive UI?

Tags: c#, wpf, timeout, reactive-programming, system.reactive

I need to disable WPF UI in my application when any of the 2 ReactiveCommands on the page is executed. Commands are called one by one. It means that they are invoked the following way:

```
Command1
   .Select(x => ...Prepare params for second...)
   .InvokeCommand(Command2)
   .DisposeWith(d);
```

I made an observable like:

```
IObservable<bool> CanInteractWithUserObservable => Command1.IsExecuting
                                        .CombineLatest(Command2.IsExecuting, (c1,c2)=>(c1,c2))
                                        .Select(tuple => tuple.c1 || tuple.c2)
                                        .Select(res => !res)
                                        .ObserveOn(RxApp.MainThread);
```

and bound it to the Window.IsEnabled property.

Generally, it works, but the problem that the observable returns value *true* when 1 command *finished* its job, but second did not start yet. So, the overall output is:

> true; // Before start
>
> false; // First command executing
>
> true; // *First command finished, second not started yet* (It is problem)
>
> false; // Second command executing
>
> true; // Both commands finished

I need to listen to sequence and only after half-second or so from the last real event I should publish an update in mine CanInteractWithUserObservable to avoid UI blinking.

P.S.: Probably Timeout method may help me, but I didn't get how to use it.

Comment: What does "commands are called one by one" actually mean? How do you know that the second command will always be executed right after the first one has finished? How do you invoke the commands?

Comment: So you are invoking the command from the view...? Please provide a reproducible example of your issue when asking a question.

Comment: @mm8, I think the invocation does not mean here anything. There is a sequence given, and I need to alter it a bit. There is no chance that the initial sequence will be changed.

Comment: The question is *how* you are supposed to "alter" it.

Comment: @mm8, yes, it is. Please edit the title or something, because my understanding that I asked correctly.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand correctly you want to wait both 2 event to be complete and then let your UI released.

```
Command1.IsExecuting
.CombineLatest(Command2.IsExecuting, (c1,c2)=>(c1,c2))
.Select(tuple => tuple.c1 && tuple.c2) // instead of or use and so only when both will be done value will be true
.SkipWhile(t=> t == false) // omit when both not completed 
.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(.5)) // i don't know you still want to wait 0.5 seconds more but Delay is the operator for that
.Select(res => !res)
.ObserveOn(RxApp.MainThread);
```

`Timeout` is used for to emitting error when an observable doesn't emit a value for amount of given value.

Comment: I am sorry, this won't suit me. It will pass ` third true` anyway, which I don't need. And it won't pass `false` when commands execute. I need `false` to disable UI.